# How to use thread.abort()

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-abort

I am simply trying to abort thread by clicking a button to stop the process if user wanted instead of exiting the application.

This is original code:

```
 private void Abort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //   thread1.Abort();
    }

    ///  Runs method 'Copy' in a new thread with passed arguments - on this way we separate it from UI thread otherwise it would freeze
    private void backgroundCopy_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e )
    {

        List<object> genericlist = e.Argument as List<object>;
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => Copy(genericlist[0].ToString(), genericlist[1].ToString()));
        thread1.Start();
        thread1.Join(); //Waiting for thread to finish
    }
```

What I have tried:

I tried Abort() thread from button click event by moving thread field out of method, that way you can get access from your button click event, but it throws many errors:

```
 object sender;
 System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e;
 List<object> genericlist = e.Argument as List<object>;
 Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => Copy(genericlist[0].ToString(), genericlist[1].ToString()));



 private void Abort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     thread1.Abort();
 }

 ///  Runs method 'Copy' in a new thread with passed arguments - on this way we separate it from UI 
  thread otherwise it would freeze
 private void backgroundCopy_DoWork( )
 {


     thread1.Start();
     thread1.Join(); //Waiting for thread to finish
 }
```

That's what I did but I get error:

> under e and genericlist : a field initialize can not reference a non static field, method or property.

Comment: Please use a `CancellationTokenSource` and `CancellationToken` to cancel long running background processes instead of Thread.Abort. You should not use Thread.Abort unless you're prepared to tear down your process afterwards. Thread.Abort is slightly safer than it used to be, but it still isn't safe to use unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Have you considered a Task or a `List<Task>` using a `CancellationTokenSource` so you can simply pass a `CancellationToken` to the Task(s)? You can await a single Task or use `await Task.WhenAll()` instead of using a BackgroundWorker in that manner.

Comment: It's generally better to allow the thread or task to monitor some token so it can self-terminate gracefully.  `Thread.Abort` is anything but graceful.

Comment: @Jimi I am near the end of the project therefor I don't want to make a lot of changes.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Assume user wants to lose his progress and just abort everything and start over.

Comment: If you don't make those changes now you'll have to painfully make them later.

Comment: @Jimi I have a dead line.

Comment: @CountLessQ We *all* have deadlines.  Welcome to the club.

Comment: You can use `worker.CancelAsync()`.  See here for an example: https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/cancelling-the-backgroundworker/

Comment: Define "start over", if you mean "exit the program and start it again", then fine. But if you mean "cancel the long running process, and then restart it, without restarting the program", then no, don't use Thread.Abort.

Comment: If you use Thread.Abort and don't know how to write code that will be able to be safely killed, you're going to have a ton of problems down the line, probably starting immediately as your code runs in production. Thread.Abort is reserved for system code, not for user code, you should use proper cooperative cancellation instead of forced killing.

Comment: You'll miss the deadline when that code won't work as expected or produce unpredictable results in unpredictable occasions (if you can reliably get this thing to work at all). Using Tasks makes it really simpler (and actually reliable).

Comment: @CountLessQ You came here seeking help from experienced programmers.  Those experienced programmers are now telling you that using `Thread.Abort()` is a bad idea.  We are telling you that for very good reasons.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen let say you want to copy a large folder then it took soo long so you abort it lose the progress and go start copying new folder that is smaller and faster instead of just exiting the application click abort

Comment: The main reason the compiler is complaining is that you've put the code that has the errors in the wrong place, put it inside a method, not as field initializers.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen if you want Abort() thread from button click event you need to move thread field out of method, that way you can get access from your button click event.

Comment: Thread field, yes, but move the initialization code, the part after the `=` to a method.

Comment: @Amy i appreciate the advice and I too know those reasons.

Comment: The list of cautions in the documentation is so long and exhaustive that anybody with a lick of sense will avoid using `Thread.Abort()` unless there is absolutely no possible way to terminate the thread by any other means. Learn from our mistakes: *do not use* `Thread.Abort`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @RobertHarvey can you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case you have to use threads, try this. Otherwise, try cancelAsync like in this link:
https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/cancelling-the-backgroundworker/

```
     // We will set this true to notify the worker threads return.
            private bool shouldAbort;
    // when hitting submit set:
    shouldAbort = false;
    void MethodThatDoesWork()
        {
                //we should stop if required
                if (shouldAbort)
                {
                    state.Stop();
                }
            //code
        }
```

we must be sure that all threads are terminated when the form is closed.
so we add these controls.

```
   private void ItemsCopyer_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
       {
         System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }

        private void btnAbort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            shouldAbort = true;
            btnAbort.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 13):

> How to use thread.abort()

You do *not* use `Thread.Abort()`, *ever*, unless you are doing an emergency shutdown of an entire application domain or process.  You **NEVER DO THIS**.  I hope that is very clear.

A few reasons you never do this are:

1. There are many better ways to control cancellation of an asynchronous workflow than aborting it.
2. Aborting a thread is not guaranteed to actually abort the thread. A thread which is actively resisting being aborted has ways to delay the abort indefinitely.  It is not reliable, so don't use it.
3. Most important: aborting a thread is guaranteed to maintain the correctness **of the internal mechanisms used by the CLR to manage the thread**.  It is **not** guaranteed to maintain the correctness of your program!  A thread abort can cause your program invariants to be violated in interesting ways which frequently lead to crashes.  (Exercise: list the possible consequences of a thread abort happening during the construction of an object with a finalizer)

The right way to structure your program is to use a cooperative cancellation pattern, and represent your asynchronous work as a task that can be cancelled. The asynchronous work then periodically polls the token to see if it needs to cancel itself.

Moreover: *if the asynchronous work is not processor bound, then the right solution is to not use a worker thread*. Rather, use asynchronous IO and `await` the result. You would not hire a worker to stand by your mailbox and tell you when letters arrived; similarly, do not hire a worker to stand around waiting for an IO task to complete.  Keep the asynchronous work on the main thread if it is not CPU bound, and your thread will keep servicing user requests while it waits.

> I got an error `a field initializer can not reference a non static field, method or property.`

That's correct.  A field initializer cannot use `this` in *any* way, including an implicit use inside the body of a lambda.   The reason for this is because *the field initializer runs before the body of the constructor runs*, but it is the body of the constructor that initializes the fields of `this`.  The language design is trying to save you from writing a nasty bug here.

You need to move your initialization logic into a constructor.

But more generally, if your program requirements are that you must asynchronously perform high-latency IO bound tasks that can be canceled by the user, then you have chosen the wrong mechanisms to correctly and safely achieve that goal.

> I am near the end of the project therefor I don't want to make a lot of changes.

I'm sure you don't.  The sooner you start fixing your architectural problems, the sooner you will have a correct, safe implementation.

> I have a deadline

That's a management problem, not a technical one. My advice is that you explain the situation to your management. They deserve to know that the choices are to meet the deadline with an incorrectly structured and possibly unstable program, or to extend the deadline and restructure the program into a principled, correct, safe program that meets user requirements. Management should have the right to make an informed decision about the state of the project they're paying you for.

Comment: This looks like a great, comprehensive answer, but I would be minded to recommend removing the section about deadlines (and the bit about not making architectual changes because of a lack of time). Answers should really focus on the technical parts of the question asked, and they should be relevant to a wide audience - material about these general SWE problems doesn't really meet either of these requirements.